# MVC2 DataAnnotations with Server-side validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

How do you validate an entity containing DataAnnotations without using the MVC library? Using Model.IsValid is fine when you're within the Presentation layer, but what about when you want to ensure the model is valid in the Domain/Business layer? Do I need a separate validation framework, or is there an easy way I'm missing?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean ModelState.IsValid by Model.IsValid, right? Well, DataAnnotions don't depend on MVC at all, so you can always use the [IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) interface.

Or perhaps the [Validator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) will be more appropriate, by using [Validator.ValidateObject(object, ValidationContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411788.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I wrote my validation logic using plain c#, my business layer contains these validations and I use try and catch blocks throughout business layer. The presentation layer catches these custom exceptions so errors are shown on screen to the user. I only kept basic validation inside the data annotations e.g. [Required] mainly for ajax calls and to notify users to enter data in non nullable fields, that way my business logic remained in my middle tier, it remained consistent, it remained in only one place which I can refer to.